Facing error "panic has occurred: /api/v2/write?org=test\bucket=test\precision=s: runtime error: integer divide by zero" when writing to influxdb2.7.4
I have installed influxdb 2.7.4 docker container on AWS EC2 having AL2023 OS image. I copied the data from S3 to this docker container and this data file in compressed format is around 4 GB. I restored this data into influxdb successfully. However, facing the below error when trying to write to influxdb from my code, which uses curl for influxdb writes.
{"code":"internal error","message":"a panic has occurred: /api/v2/write?org=test\bucket=test\precision=s: runtime error: integer divide by zero"}
The above steps seems to work perfectly fine with docker container on AWS EC2 having CentOS.
Any quick pointers to the above problem will be helpful.
We have faced this panic error two times till now. First time we were able to resolve this issue by deleting the existing bucket and restoring the data from S3 again. But this workaround is not working now and still facing the mentioned panic error.

Try to do the following:

Create a new bucket (i.e. new_bucket)

Run a query to copy the contents of problem bucket (i.e. old_bucket) to the new bucket:
from(bucket: "old_bucket")
|> range(start: 1970-01-01T22:00:00Z)
|> to(bucket: "new_bucket", org: "myorg")

Rename the old_bucket to some name (or delete it)

Rename the new_bucket to old_bucket

Re-create authorization tokens


Of course it's not convenient for buckets with a lot of data, but probably better than nothing
